# CKAN Datapusher PDF gives "IndexError: pop from empty list" when uploading to datastore

Tags: ckan

I am trying to set up a CKAN website (latest stable version: 2.5.0a). I have one locally in a VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 Lts as test environment and one running on a Ubuntu 14.04 Lts server as a production website. Both of them were set up following the tutorial. Solr was deployed using Tomcat and the production server was deployed using Apache2.

I was trying to set up the datastore, file_store, resource_proxy and datapusher in order to be able to upload or link files (csv, pdf,...), index them and create views for resources.

On my local test machine, I managed to set up all of these. When I link or upload a csv file, all works well. But when I upload or link a pdf file, I get the following error from the datapusher:

```
Fetching from: http://127.0.0.1:5000/dataset/e336410b-5d3d-4669-a29a-0f7c114077e5/resource/396941c8-a56c-4673-b232-cd7a9bc0faf6/download/test.pdf
Job "push_to_datastore (trigger: RunTriggerNow, run = True, next run at: None)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/home/bart/ckan/lib/default/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 343, in push_to_datastore
    row_set = table_set.tables.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

When trying the same on my production environment, I get the same error when linking a pdf file. But uploading any file (csv, pdf,...) gives me the following error:

```
Fetching from: http://my_site_ip_here/dataset/72d76b70-c6bc-4d00-a753-6d1477375fd1/resource/55bab371-781b-4938-97b9-225e1534ca52/download/newusers.csv
ec5d8eb6-a277-41aa-b483-ae229595bf08
Job "push_to_datastore (trigger: RunTriggerNow, run = True, next run at: None)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ckan/lib/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 306, in push_to_datastore
    DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT)
JobError
```

Linking a csv file on my production site works.
Concerning the JobError I found out that I can download my file based on the "Fetching from" link in the error. However, when I try to download the file from another browser or computer using the same link it doesn't work (notice this is only for uploaded files).

The code that gives the error is

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT)
```

Located as described in jobs.py, function push_to_datastore Line number 297.

So my questions are:

1. What could be wrong with my datapusher on my production server?
2. Why do pdf files give the specific error on both production and development, while other filetypes work?
3. What is the exact task of the resource_proxy? Shouldn't it download the linked files and set them locally available? And should the download link to the file then not be a link to my own CKAN instance in stead of the external location? This is currently not the case.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This sounds like a bug, so it would be better to raise an issue at https://github.com/ckan/datapusher

Comment: But do you think the timeout error is a bug aswel? I think I have some configuration wrong or something but I can't seem to figure it out.